# How to change color of text when hovering on anything on a card?

Tags: css

I want to change the color of header element `h4` inside a div with class `info` when i hover on a card (class `card`).

I have tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```css
.card:hover info h4 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div>
    <div class="a"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <h4> hello </h4>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Could someone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: you forgot the . for the class `.info`. It should be `.card:hover .info h4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax for `info` class

```css
.card:hover .info h4 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div>
    <div class="a"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <h4> hello </h4>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```